# IPhone X screen is partly unresponsive after update to iOS 15

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

What are your suggestion to fix it? I have tried to visualize it, and opened notes app, and tried to draw on it with a pencil. This is the result, as you can see below:

[image]

Some important informations:

- scroll up and down works in that black hole
- in that space where the black hole exists also keyboard buttons doesn't work at all: **j** and **n**.

Is there a way to fix it?

Is it possible that something happened to my iPhone only? I think it is because update to iOS 15, but I am not sure.

What can I do with this?

Comment: This seems like a hardware issue on your phone. However, you can still revert to iOS 14 to verify this. Will require resetting your phone: https://www.theverge.com/22557790/ios-beta-install-restore-iphone (skip over profile removal steps)

Comment: But why it happened right now?;) Is it just coincidence that happened along with the update?

Comment: I don't think the update caused this.  I've scoured the internet and I had every beta installed on my iPhone X, I can't find anything where this is related.

Comment: @fsb may it be related to this program? https://support.apple.com/iphone-x-display-module-replacement-program

Comment: Maybe but that's a hardware failure and not related to an OS update.  It's extremely difficult to troubleshoot a hardware issue on this site.  You need to contact Apple Support directly.

Comment: @fsb I will go to the store tomorrow to check my iphone... Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: If I had to guess, it was likely a hardware issue that hadn't "been an issue" until the phone likely got hot during the software update.  Might have been that little bit of heat that put it over the edge and made the issue apparent.  Unfortunately.